# How to disable Button save in angular 6 when use ngIf errors

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular6

I Have problem when i click save, error message " Cannot read property 'required' of null
    at Object.eval [as updateDirectives]"

This my code html

```
 <form name="dataForm" [formGroup]="dataForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
        <div class="mb-24" fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="start start" [ngClass]="{'has-error': ((dataForm.get('usernames').touched ||
        dataForm.get('usernames').dirty) &&
        dataForm.get('usernames').errors)}">
            <mat-form-field fxFlex>
                <input matInput placeholder=" Username" formControlName="usernames">
                <mat-error *ngIf="((dataForm.get('usernames').touched ||
                    dataForm.get('usernames').dirty) &&
                    dataForm.get('usernames').errors).required">
                    Username empty
                </mat-error>
            </mat-form-field>
        </div>
```

this button

```
 <button mat-raised-button class="save-button mat-accent" type="submit" (click)="showToaster()"
                [mat-dialog-close] [disabled]="dataForm.errors.required? true: null">Save</button>&nbsp;
```

Comment: You did not share the ts code... In form group, usernames (plural) or username (singular) coded.

Comment: <mat-error *ngIf="((dataForm.get('usernames').touched ||
                    dataForm.get('usernames').dirty) &&
                    dataForm.get('usernames').errors && (dataForm.get('usernames').errors).required">
                    Username empty
                </mat-error>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply do `[disabled]="!dataForm.valid"`.

Answer (score 0):

My ts

```
ngOnInit() {
this.dataForm= this.formBuilder.group({
  usernames: ['', [Validators.required]],
});}
```

Answer (score 0):

looks like your `dataForm.get('usernames').errors).required` causing the problem
either check `dataForm.get('usernames').errors` is not null before call its `required` property or try just use `dataForm.get('usernames').errors` without calling `required` property given you only have one rule for that field

edited with the code

```
<mat-error *ngIf="((dataForm.get('usernames').touched ||
                dataForm.get('usernames').dirty) &&
                dataForm.get('usernames').errors)">
                Username empty
            </mat-error>
```

removed the `.required`
for the button part, either use `[disabled]="dataForm.errors&&dataForm.errors.required? true: null"`
or `[disabled]="dataForm.errors? true: null"`

Comment: When i remove required, i get error "Cannot read property 'required' of null
    at Object.eval [as updateDirectives]"

Comment: missed your button part, please check the updated answer